# Problem with Integration using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

OK, so here is a question from integration that I recently stumbled upon.

- Evaluate $I =\int\cos^3\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta$

Now here's how I tried to solve it first;

$\text{Substitute} \cos\theta = t$
The integral reduces to-
 $I = -\int\,t^3\,dt$
or $I = -\,t^4/4+C$ 
$I = -\cos^4\theta\,/4+C$

Now here's the second method;

$\text{Substitute} \sin\theta = t$
The integral reduces to-
 $I = \int\,(1-t^2)t\,dt$
or $I = t^2/2 - t^4/4 + C$ 
$I = \sin^2\theta\,/2 - \sin^4\theta\,/4 + C$

The primitive comes out to be different in the two cases.
What am I missing?

Comment: If you differentiate both of your results, do you get the original function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that differentiating either result gives you the original function.  What this tells you is that the two functions differ by a constant.  That "difference by a constant" is something we normally take for granted.  So, it's easy to forget that
$$
\int 2x\,dx = x^2 + C\\
\int 2x\,dx = x^2 + 1 + C
$$
are both valid, since they refer to the same *family of functions*.  In the case of your function, we note that
$$
\left[\frac 12 \sin^2\theta - \frac 14 \sin^4\theta\right] - \left[-\frac 14 \cos^4 \theta\right] =\\
\frac 12 \sin^2\theta - \frac 14[\sin^4\theta - \cos^4 \theta] =\\
\frac 12 \sin^2\theta - \frac 14[\sin^2\theta - \cos^2 \theta] =\\
\frac 14[\sin^2\theta + \cos^2 \theta] = \frac 14
$$